# changing text of custom navigation bar item

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating a custom UINavigationBar BarButtonItem as follows:

```
 // Set up bar button items
    UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35.0f, 35.0f)];
    [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myselector) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
```

This is working perfectly, but when I go to set the title of the UIButton or BarButtonItem, it won't show up. Any suggestions?

**Tried...**

```
    [backButton setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**And...**

```
     self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = @"Edit";
```

without luck.

Comment: It might have to do with you setting the image and trying to overwrite the image with your own text.

Comment: Try this to set image : [backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: Why not just have the text "Edit" on your button image?

Comment: @CRDave that was it. The image and text were fighting for space so I was only seeing the image while the text was kicked off to the side, outside of the barbutton view.

Comment: @CRDave answer the question so @A user can accept it

Comment: @Auser Your problem solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that image and title use same viewspace for display.

So when we use image with title first it show image and than title (right side of image).

If size of `UIButton` is same as image than we can't see Title.

A simple solution is set image in background. So try this:

```
[backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myimg.png"];
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[backButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [backButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]
backButton.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 35.0f, 35.0f);

UIBarButtonItem *barButton= [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton] autorelease];
self.toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:barButton];
```